# How to add custom line to BoxWhisker holoviews plot?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, boxplot, holoviews

I need to add a horizontal line to the boxplot. Looked through `holoviews` manual and seems that [`HLine`](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HLine.html#bokeh-gallery-hline) is supposed to be used in such case. Unfortunately I get an error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts

hv.extension('bokeh')

groups = [chr(65+g) for g in np.random.randint(0, 3, 200)]

boxwhisker = hv.BoxWhisker(
    (groups, np.random.randint(0, 5, 200), np.random.randn(200)),
    ['Group', 'Category'], 
    'Value'
).sort() * hv.HLine(1)

boxwhisker.opts(
    opts.BoxWhisker(
        box_color='white', 
        height=400, 
        show_legend=False, 
        whisker_color='gray', 
        width=600
    ),
    opts.HLine(color='green', line_width=2)
)

layout = hv.Layout(boxwhisker)
hv.save(layout, 'boxplot.html')
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/renderer.py", line 545, in save
    plot = self_or_cls.get_plot(obj)
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/renderer.py", line 135, in get_plot
    plot = super(BokehRenderer, self_or_cls).get_plot(obj, renderer, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/renderer.py", line 207, in get_plot
    plot.update(init_key)
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/plot.py", line 595, in update
    return self.initialize_plot()
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/plot.py", line 995, in initialize_plot
    subplots = subplot.initialize_plot(ranges=ranges, plots=shared_plots)
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/plot.py", line 1115, in initialize_plot
    adjoined_plots.append(subplot.initialize_plot(ranges=ranges, plots=passed_plots))
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py", line 2058, in initialize_plot
    self._update_ranges(element, ranges)
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py", line 747, in _update_ranges
    xfactors, yfactors = self._get_factors(element, ranges)
  File "/home/python3.6/site-packages/holoviews/plotting/bokeh/element.py", line 2031, in _get_factors
    xfactors = np.concatenate(xfactors)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HLine is the right way to do this, but unfortunately the support for categorical axes in HoloViews is currently limited and will not allow such an overlay. There's been some work on an unfinished [alternative implementation for categorical axes](https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews/pull/3385) that would fix this. In the meantime, I'd assume you could add a [custom hook](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html#Plot-hooks), but that would be awkward to figure out.

Note that `hv.Layout(boxwhisker)` won't work as you have it above, in any case; it would need to be `hv.Layout([boxwhisker])` or just `boxwhisker` (as Layout takes a list, but here you don't even need a layout since you have only one item).

Comment: Do you have an idea how the hook would look like for this case?